# Web App mode leaves users stranded when following image links when using WPTouch with W3 Total Cache

Tags: images, plugin-w3-total-cache, mobile, plugin-wptouch

In most of the posts on my site, embedded images link to the actual image file. I'm also using Web-App mode via WPTouch. In web-app mode images linked to their larger versions shouldn't open; since Web-App mode has no back button, a user can follow a link to a image and become "stranded" there.

I'm also using W3 Total Cache, which appends the param string "?9d7bd4" to all my images. This makes sure that if you change your browser cache policies all users immediately see that change.

However, apparently the the appended image string allows for the images to be clicked on and stranded. Interferes with whatever is stripping the image links.

All BraveNewCode can tell me is try "disabling Browser Cache in W3TC" which I obviously I'm not interested in doing. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to avoid this is to go to "Browser Cache" and uncheck "Prevent caching of objects after settings change" under "Media and Other Files"